# How can I update array value with specific condition with angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an external json with a list of names.
Something like

```
{id:1,name:'AAA',age:22},{id:2,name:'AAA',age:100}
```

I have one of this with an error.
I know the right ID.
I can't edit the original data.

So, i would like to update the right age in the json before print all data with ng-repat, if ID = 2

How can i update the array with angular?

Comment: `Loop..  Condition..  Update Object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the array and set the `rightAge` for the user with `id` equal to 2.

Code:

```js
const arr = [{id:1,name:'AAA',age:22},{id:2,name:'AAA',age:100}];
const rightAge = 20; // example right age
  
arr.map(u => u.age = u.id === 2 ? rightAge : u.age);

// Ready to show in the view
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```